# Null Pointer exception in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var Obj = {

    StateValues: ['AL','AK','AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
    'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND',
    'OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY'],

    getItemRow: function(itemValue) {
     var myPosition=-1
       for (var i=0;i<Obj.StateValues.length;i++) {
          if(Obj.StateValues[i]==itemValue) {
            myPosition = i;
             break;
         }
      }
      return myPosition;
    }
}
```

When i add the function in the code, i get `Null Pointer Expection`. This piece of code is in a sep file... somename.js and which i include

I am not even using this function anywhere in my other js file... like Obj.getItemRow()

Comment: I dont get any errors running it.

Comment: @Petah: Is it because, i am including this js file in another class... which is causing this issue. when i include this file, will the function get called without using it... ???

Comment: Well give us a complete code sample

Comment: Isn't `Obj.getItemRow(itemValue)` the same as `Obj.StateValues.indexOf(itemValue)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Obj = new function(){

     var StateValues = ['AL','AK','AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
    'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND',
    'OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY'];

    this.getItemRow = function(itemValue) {
     var myPosition=-1
       for (var i=0;i<StateValues.length;i++) {
          if(StateValues[i]==itemValue) {
            myPosition = i;
             break;
         }
      }
      return myPosition;
    };
}
```

This is an easier way to create objects.

`var blah = 'this is private'`
`this.blah = 'this is public'`

Comment: i did not get your easier way of creating objects... could you explain me in detail.. willing to learn

Comment: It's pretty simple. Instead of creating a raw object, you create a function with a persistent allocation space. I'm not sure why your way is getting NPEs, but my first step in any problem is replace anything complicated with its simpler equivalent.

Comment: can you lead me to some example of your usage

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
console.debug(Obj.getItemRow("AK"));
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Obj is not defined